# Eigen C++ crashes on matrix multiplication with openMP support enabled

Tags: c++, visual-studio, openmp, eigen

I have the following C++ Eigen code that simply multiplies two matrices together in non-parallel and parallel processing fashion and compares the timing. I am using Visual Studio 2022 in Windows 10. I have enabled OpenMP Support in my VS project.

My code works perfectly as long as the matrix size is `M < 250`. With this code, matrix multiplication was accelerated by a factor of 2.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <Eigen/Dense>

int main() {
    const int M = 250;

    Eigen::MatrixXd A = Eigen::MatrixXd::Ones(M, M);
    Eigen::MatrixXd B = Eigen::MatrixXd::Ones(M, M);

    auto start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    Eigen::MatrixXd C = A * B;
    auto end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    auto durationWithoutParallel = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(end - start).count();

    Eigen::initParallel();
    start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    Eigen::MatrixXd D = A * B;
    end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    auto durationWithParallel = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(end - start).count();

    std::cout << "Matrix multiplication without parallel processing: " << durationWithoutParallel << " ms" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Matrix multiplication with parallel processing: " << durationWithParallel << " ms" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

If I, for example, try `M = 1000`, my code crashes on calculating `C`, which is part of my code that parallel computation is not still enabled.

- Without OpenMP support, my code runs successfully for `M = 1000` (of course there will be no acceleration).
- With MP support, it crashes for `M = 1000` on the computation of `C`. It only works for approximately `M < 250`.

The crash occurs on the following line in `Eigen/src/Core/products/GeneralMatrixMatrix.h`

```
ei_declare_aligned_stack_constructed_variable(RhsScalar, blockB, sizeB, 0);
```

Could someone kindly help, please?

Comment: This is likely because Windows provides very small stack space for threads (not sure if and how it is possible to increase that). You could (before including Eigen) set Eigen's stack allocation limit to a much smaller value by defining `EIGEN_STACK_ALLOCATION_LIMIT`.